# Through two distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ passes a unique line

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am asked to prove the following statement: Through two distinct points $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $a\neq b$, there passes a unique line $l$.

If we have a line given by $L_{a,b} = \{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 = d \}$, how would we prove this statement? Writing it as a system of equations and showing the solution is unique? There is surely a better way, isn't it?

I tried something like this, but I am not very confident this will work:

If $l$ contains $a$ and $b$, then (after some rearranging) we have $c_1(a_1-b_1) + c_2(a_2-b_2) = 0$, now suppose there is another line containing these points. Let's call it $l'$. This should look like this: $c'_1(a_1-b_1) + c'_2(a_2-b_2) = 0$

So we see, apart from being scalable with a factor $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $, these are the same line.

However, I am fairly unconfident this proves anything.
How would we go about this, without using the dimension of the solution space of the equations or linear independence etc.?

Comment: Hint: Show that any point $(x, y)$ on a line through $a$ and $b$ satisfies
$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & y & 1\\
a_1 & a_2 & 1\\
b_1 & b_2 & 1
\end{vmatrix} = 0.$$
What do you get after expanding the determinant?

Comment: Thanks, but no determinants

Comment: This looks like a fine start. The gap remaining is the possibility of different values of $d$.

Comment: $L_{a,b} = \{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 = d \}$, with $(c_1,c_2)\color{red}{\neq (0,0)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : c_1x_1 + c_2x_2 = d \}$, with $(c_1,c_2)\neq(0,0)$ such that $$\begin {cases}\color{blue}{c_1a_1+c_2a_2=d(*)}\\c_1b_1+c_2b_2=d\end{cases}$$

Let $l'=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : c_1'x_1 + c_2'x_2 = d' \}$, with $(c_1',c_2')\neq(0,0)$ such that $$\begin {cases}c_1'a_1+c_2'a_2=d'\\c_1'b_1+c_2'b_2=d'\end{cases}$$
So, as you pointed out, $\exists \lambda \color{red}{\neq0},(c_1',c_2')=\lambda(c_1,c_2)$

So, $l'=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lambda c_1x_1 + \lambda c_2x_2 = d' \}$

$(a_1,a_2)\in l'$. Then, $\lambda c_1a_1 + \lambda c_2a_2 = d'$. But $\lambda c_1a_1 + \lambda c_2a_2=\lambda(c_1a_1+c_2a_2)=\lambda d$, according to $\color{blue}{(*)}$.

So, $d'=\lambda d $.

Then, $$l'=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lambda c_1x_1 + \lambda c_2x_2 = \lambda d \}$$
$$l'=\{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lambda (c_1x_1 +  c_2x_2 - d)=0 \}=l,$$since $\lambda\neq 0.$